# Group by max value for each day

Tags: sql, sorting, group

| ID | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2023-10-12 16:10:59.457 |
| 1 | 20 | 2023-10-12 14:20:54.997 |
| 1 | 30 | 2023-10-13 10:30:59.457 |
| 1 | 70 | 2023-10-13 10:20:54.997 |
| 2 | 10 | 2023-10-12 18:00:59.457 |
| 2 | 20 | 2023-10-13 14:00:54.997 |

I have a table with and ID, some values and a Date fiel and I want to group than by ID and day but just taking the max date value of each ID. My DB is SQL Server.

| ID | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2023-10-12 16:10:59.457 |
| 1 | 30 | 2023-10-13 10:30:59.457 |
| 2 | 10 | 2023-10-12 18:00:59.457 |
| 2 | 20 | 2023-10-13 14:00:54.997 |

Comment: In PostgreSQL you can use `DISTINCT ON`. What's your database?

Comment: PostgreSQL: `select distinct on (id, date(date)) * from t order by id, date(date), value desc`.

Comment: If your second table is supposed to be the desired result it does not match the sample data you provided. Max value for day 12 id 1 is 20. Unless I understood what you need wrong. Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Windowing concept to solve this problem.

```
SELECT id,
   value,
   date,
   ROW_NUMBER(date) OVER
     (PARTITION BY id,TO_DATE(date) ORDER BY date DESC)
     AS row_number
  FROM YOUR_TABLE 
WHERE row_number = 1
```

There would be additional column `row_number` which developer need to remove or ignore. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer that might be usefull in your case.

I prepared creation scripts based on given information so you can check how it should work.

**Create Scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (id INTEGER, value NUMBER, date_time DATE);
```

**Insert Scripts:**

```
Insert into test_table (id,value,date_time) values (1,10,to_date('2023-10-12 16:10:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))

Insert into test_table (id,value,date_time) values (1,20,to_date('2023-10-12 14:20:54','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))

Insert into test_table (id,value,date_time) values (1,30,to_date('2023-10-13 10:30:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))

Insert into test_table (id,value,date_time) values (1,70,to_date('2023-10-13 10:20:54','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))

Insert into test_table (id,value,date_time) values (2,10,to_date('2023-10-12 18:00:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))

Insert into test_table (id,value,date_time) values (2,20,to_date('2023-10-13 14:00:54','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

**Solution:**

```
with max_data as
(
    SELECT ID
           ,MAX(date_time) AS date_time -- select max date for each ID
    FROM test_table 
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT md.id
       ,md.date_time
       ,tt.value
FROM test_table tt
JOIN max_data md ON tt.date_time=md.date_time and tt.id=md.id
```

The solution assumes that you have a compound primary key that consist of `id` and `date_time`- since every row in a table should have an unique primary key.

**How it works:**

Firstly it gets a record with max `date_time` for each `id` from the `test_table`, and then joins to the same table to grab a `value` column.